# How do I send single character ASCII data to a serial port with python

Tags: python, arduino

I'v looked at pyserial but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I only need to send one at a time? Please help?

Answer (score 7):

Using [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#classes):

Python 2.x:

```
import serial
byte = 42
out = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")  # "COM1" on Windows
out.write(chr(byte))
```

Python 3.x:

```
import serial
byte = 42
out = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")  # "COM1" on Windows
out.write(bytes(byte))
```

Answer (score 1):

Google says:

1. http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/
2. http://balder.prohosting.com/ibarona/en/python/uspp/uspp_en.html

if you're using Uspp; to write on serial port [documentation says](http://balder.prohosting.com/ibarona/en/python/uspp/uspp_en.html#Section5)